# What does "I have times from Tuesday on" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I wanted to arrange an appointment from my professor on Skype, then he answered my email:

> **I have times from Tuesday on**

What exactly does it mean?   does he mean I can have the time just on Tuesday or does it mean he has time from Tuesday onward?

Answer (score 1):

In the phrase "I have times..." the verb **have** is in the present simple, which relates to now: what it indicates in this context is that he currently has time slots that are unallocated on the specified dates in the future... but they may be taken soon.

**on** in this context is a shortened form of **onwards**: here is a definition from the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on).

> **on adverb (MOVING FORWARD)**
>   ​> B2 continuing forward in time or space

Looking at your sentence,

> I have times from Tuesday on...

Means the prof currently has time slots for appointments available on Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday... You can get back to him and say

> What times are available on Tuesday?
>  
>   What times are available on Wednesday?
>  
>   When are you available on Tuesday?

If you want Tuesday, you need to get back to him quickly: if you leave it too long, he may say to you

> I **had** times on Tuesday, but ...

The use of simple past **had** means that, at some time in the past (and in particular when he originally wrote to you), there were available slots on Tuesday, but there are no longer any available.